# Bot framework localization languages

Tags: c#, botframework

First of all, sorry because i don´t speak english very well.
At this moment i am working on a bot with microsoft bot framework and we have a simple problem.
We need to have the posibility to choose english or spanish. We made resx files and it worked... but when we tried from two channels at the same time, the bot works like one exclusive entity... if i put spanish in telegram and my colleague put english, then my text and buttons goes english.
We tried making simple flag at the beginning of the bot, and force it to start in english because cortana only work in english... but the problem continues. Cortana tried to speak our spanish text in english...
How can we force that all the "session" of one user with the bot use the same languange and don't affect other users?
Thanks

Comment: What version of the Bot Framework SDK are you using?

Comment: We are using 3.8.1 version

Comment: Localization should function as expected (based on current thread's CurrentUiCulture and CurrentCulture).  Please post a simplified version of your code.

Comment: We finally solved it. With CurrentUiCulture and CurrentCulture and some tricks with BotData and BotState... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this using Strings.resx files is as so (within any dialog):

```
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.PostAsync($"Hi!");
            PromptDialog.Choice(context,
                HandleLang,
                new[] { "English", "Espanol"},
                "Please select a language:",
                "I didn't get that");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }


        public async Task HandleLang(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            string lang = await result as string;
            switch (lang)
            {
                case "English":
                    Strings.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    break;
                case "Espanol":
                    Strings.Culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            ... do whatever here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I only use this method to localization languages.

```
 Resources.Global.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You may refer to this [GitHub](https://github.com/cheahengsoon/MultiLangBot_V4M3/blob/master/MultiLangBot_V4M3/MultiLangBot.cs). Hope it may help you.